# concatenate strings to a variable assigned as None in python

Tags: python

I was wondering why you cant concatenate strings to a variable assigned as None in python. i understand its used as a logical test, but how would you keep a variable empty before you decide it should be a string, integer.
sorry this is the code i was doing

## gets input from the user

preScraWord = input("\n\n\nPlease enter your word: ")

## turning it to lower case and getting length of word

preScraWord = preScraWord.lower()

lenWord = len(preScraWord)

nLenWord = -lenWord-1

backWord = None

for i in range(-1, nLenWord, -1):

```
backWord += preScraWord[i]
```

## print the word

print(backWord)

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: You don't have to declare variable types in Python.  You could set `x=1` on one line then `x=None` on the next, and then `x='one'` on the next.  Why do you want to have an "empty" variable?

Comment: **WE WANT THE CODE........... WE WANT THE CODE**

Comment: i wanted to have an empty variable so i could append an indexed word. didnt understand why i couldnt use None instead of an empty string ""

Comment: "how would you keep a variable empty before you decide it should be a string, integer" - why are you in a situation where you don't know whether you're going to use the variable for a string or an integer? Why would `backWord` ever be an integer?

Comment: i just wanted to now why none couldnt be used and it kept failing i wouldnt maintain a none variable for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the OP's problem is having something like:

```
def f(i):
    if i == 1:
        return "a string"
```

Then wants to do something like:

```
a = ''
for i in range(5):
    a += f(i)
```

This will throw an exception when `i > 1`, because in that case `f(i)` returns `None` which cannot be concatenated with the previous value of `a`, which was `"a string"`.

There are several ways to deal with this:

1.
Check the type of the return of `f()` before concatenation: (LBYL)

```
a = ''
for i in range(5):
    temp = f(i)
    a = a if temp is None else a + temp
    # this will skip the concatenation if temp is None
```

2.
Catch the `TypeError` exception: (EAFP)

```
a = ''
for i in range(5):
    try:
        a += f(i)
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

3.
change the thing that is creating the `None` value: (wisdom)

```
def f(i):
    if i == 1:
        return "a string"
    return ""
```

Comment: no i wasnt trying to create a function at this point. what i was trying to do was to print the word backwards. i did it but i didnt understand why i couldnt use None instead of the empty string "".